# Why can we suppose a scheme is locally local affine, as an improvement to locally affine?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

$\newcommand{\spec}{\operatorname{Spec}}\newcommand{\O}{\mathcal{O}}$Liu claims the following exercise:

> Let $S$ be a locally Noetherian scheme. Let $X,Y$ be $S$-schemes of finite type and $s\in S$.
>
> Then all morphisms of $S$-schemes $\phi:X\times_S\spec\O_{S,s}\to Y\times_S\spec\O_{S,s}$ arise as the base change of some $f:X\times_SU\to Y\times_SU$ along $\spec\O_{S,s}\to U$ where $U$ is some open neighbourhood of $s$.

Ok, sure, I believe you. What I don't believe is how this applies to make the following reduction in his proof of proposition $4.2$:

> Let $Y$ be a locally Noetherian scheme, $f:X\to Y$ a separated morphism of finite type such that $\O_Y\to f_\ast\O_X$ is an isomorphism. Then there is an open $V$ of $Y$ such that $f^{-1}(V)\to V$ is an isomorphism and $X_y$ has no isolated points for $y\in Y\setminus V$.

It suffices to show for every $y\in Y$ for whom $X_y$ has an isolated point $x$, there is an open subset $W\ni y$ where $f^{-1}(W)\to W$ is an isomorphism.

It's clear that we may suppose $Y$ is affine to prove this. What's not clear is how we may suppose $Y$ is a local affine scheme, $\spec A$ for a local ring $(A,\mathfrak{m})$. It is supposed to follow from the above exercise.

I guess I am meant to consider $S=Y$; I guess $\phi$ should be $f\times1:X\times_Y\spec\O_{Y,y}\to Y\times_Y\spec\O_{Y,y}\cong\spec\O_{Y,y}$. This satisfies the same property regarding existence of an isolated point. I know $\phi$ arises as the base change of some $g:X\times_YU\to U$ where $U\ni y$ is open.... and what's the point?

Suppose we've shown this for local affine schemes, then I know $f\times 1$ has the intended property. Take $V'\subseteq\spec\O_{Y,y}$ such that $(f\times1)^{-1}(V')\to V'$ is an isomorphism. If $f\times1$ really is the base change of some $g:X\times_YU\to U$ along $\spec\O_{Y,y}\to U$, then... I'm not really sure. I need to return to $X$ somehow, but $g$ need not factor through $X\times_YU\to X$.

What's the idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed a shortcut taken here.

The statement is as follows: if $X,Y$ are schemes of finite type over some locally Noetherian scheme $S$, and if $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is an isomorphism after base changing by $\operatorname{Spec}{\mathcal{O}_{S,s}} \rightarrow S$ for some $s \in S$, then $f$ is an isomorphism after base changing by some open immersion $U \rightarrow S$ with $s \in U$.

Let’s prove it.

**Step 1**: We assume that $f$ is a closed immersion and we prove the statement.

*Proof*: we can assume that $S$, then $Y$ (hence $X$) is affine. Let’s say that $A=\mathcal{O}(S)$, $B=\mathcal{O}(Y)$ and $\mathcal{O}(X)=B/I$.

The assumption is that there is a prime $\mathfrak{p} \subset A$ such that $B_{\mathfrak{p}} \rightarrow (B/I)_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is an isomorphism. In other words, $I_{\mathfrak{p}}=0$.

Since $I$ is finitely generated, there is some $a \in A \backslash \mathfrak{p}$ with $I_a=0$. Hence $f$ is an isomorphism above the open subset $D(a) \subset S$.

**Step 2**: let $X$ be a $S$-scheme of finite type, where $S$ is locally Noetherian. Suppose that $X\times_S \operatorname{Spec}{\mathcal{O}_{S,s}}$ is empty for some $s \in S$. Then $X \times_S U$ is empty for some open subscheme $U \subset S$ containing $s$.

*Proof*: reduce to the affine case.

**Step 3**: We assume that $f$ is an immersion and we prove the statement.

*Proof*: we can assume that $S$ is affine. Let $Y’$ be an open subscheme of $Y$ such that $f$ factors through a closed immersion $g: X \rightarrow Y’$. By Step 1, we see that $g$ is an isomorphism above some open subset of $S$ containing $s$.

The conclusion follows from Step 2 applied to $Y \backslash Y’$.

**Step 4**: “Local uniqueness of a local extension”. More precisely:
Let $X,Y$ be schemes of finite type over a locally Noetherian scheme $S$ and $f,g: X \rightarrow Y$ be two $S$-morphisms that coincide after base changing by $\operatorname{Spec}{\mathcal{O}_{S,s}} \rightarrow S$ for some $s \in S$, then they in fact coincide after base changing by some open immersion $U \rightarrow S$ with $s \in U$.

*Proof*: we can shrink $S$ and assume that it is affine. Consider the scheme $Z$, which is the fibre product of $(f,g): X \rightarrow Y \times_S Y$ and the diagonal $Y \rightarrow Y \times_S Y$. It has a natural immersion into $X$, and you can check that for every $X$-scheme $T$, one has $f_{|T}=g_{|T}$ iff $T \rightarrow X$ factors through $Z$.

It follows that the natural map $X \times_S \operatorname{Spec}{\mathcal{O}_{S,s}} \rightarrow X$ factors through $Z$. Hence $Z \times_S \operatorname{Spec}{\mathcal{O}_{S,s}} \rightarrow X \times_S \operatorname{Spec}{\mathcal{O}_{S,s}}$ is an isomorphism, and we conclude using Step 3 and the universal property for $Z$.

**Step 5**: the original statement at the beginning of the answer.

*Proof*: by Qing Liu’s exercise, we can find an open subscheme $U \subset S$ containing $s$ and morphisms $f_1=f: X \times_S U \rightarrow Y \times_S U$, $g_1: Y \times_S U \rightarrow X\times_S U$ extending $f$ and $f^{-1}$ respectively (seen as morphisms of $\mathcal{O}_{S,s}$-schemes).

Now, $f_1 \circ g_1: Y \times_S U \rightarrow Y \times_S U$ is a morphism extending the identity of $Y \times_S \operatorname{Spec}{\mathcal{O}_{S,s}}$, so by Step 4 there is some open subset $s \in U’ \subset U$ such that $f_1 \circ g_1$ is the identity above $U’$.

Similarly, there is an open subscheme $s \in U’’ \subset U$ such that $g_1 \circ f_1: X \times_S U \rightarrow X \times_S U$ is the identity.

Therefore, above the open subscheme $s \in U’ \cap U’’$, $f$ is an isomorphism with inverse map $g_1$.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately there's quite a lot here which I don't follow. I could even start with the most basic, the step $1$. Why must $O(X)$ be $O(Y)/I$ for some ideal $I$? That seems to be already presupposing the answer, that $f$ is a closed immersion. I also don't see where in the definition of closed immersion you need to worry about being an isomorphism over some open subset of $S$

Comment: The answer was unclear and I edited, sorry. In steps 1 and 3, I prove the claim under some additional (strong!) assumption.

Comment: Ah that makes more sense now. There are still things for me to think about. In step 3 you treat your immersion as a closed followed by an open, but aren't immersion defined as open immersions followed by a closed?

Comment: That’s one of the quirks in the earlier versions of Qing Liu’s book. “Closed then open” is the more common definition (EGA, Stacks, etc), for instance because it is stable by composition. See the third errata list on his webpage: https://www.math.u-bordeaux.fr/~qliu/Book/index.html .

Comment: Is it really an error? I note Hartshorne uses the same definition (open *then* closed).  Do you know under what circumstances the two are equivalent? I think I agree that the more modern one of “closed follows by open” makes more sense

Comment: The two are equivalent for quasi-compact morphisms (eg when everything is Noetherian). I don’t think it’s a mistake – the book is probably consistent even with the “open then closed” definition of an immersion.

Comment: What's the idea for showing it in the quasicompact case?

Comment: I think that’s contained in one of Qing Liu’s exercises. Off the top of my head, I would say that one is simply the fact that the EGA notion (closed then open) is stable under composition, and the other is the fact that if you have a quasi-compact “EGA immersion” $f: X \rightarrow Y$, then you have a (sufficiently) well-defined scheme-theoretic image $Z$ (maybe also because $f$ is automatically separated), which is a closed subscheme of $Y$, so maybe you can prove that in this case $X \rightarrow Z$ is an open immersion.

Comment: @FShrike In my opinion, these questions should always just be blackboxed (of course you needn't feel the same). It is part of a much larger story about descending properties for morphisms of schemes. For example, what you want follows from https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/081E as $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_{S,s})=\lim U$, as $U$ runs over affine neighborhoods of $s$. You can use this to descend almost any property you want if the morphism is locally of finite presentation.

Comment: @AlexYoucis I'm a bit confused, what's "it" here? The "locally the scheme of a local ring" claim or the equivalence of definitions of immersion?

Comment: @FShrike The fact that Aphelli proves: that a morphism having property X in the limit is equivalent to it happening at one of the finite levels.